# How do I kill the pie menu when pressing TAB? - Problem resolved with thanks

Tags: interface

In earlier versions of Blender, I could press TAB to change from OBJECT to EDIT mode and back. And I could press a number to flip from vertex to edge or face selection.

Now I press TAB and I get a pie menu.

I find it horribly annoying. How do I get rid of i?

ETA - Thanks to Crantisz for providing the simple answer. All I had to do was reload factory settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the option "Tab for Pie Menu" in preferenses. Un-click it or click "Pie menu on Drag" also.

[image]

Or  "3D viewport Pie Menus" addon is the issue

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. The thing is, Tab for pie menu is n ot checked. It never has been. I've never, ever checked it.

Comment: Is 3D viewport Pie Menus disabled? Try to load factory settings.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so very much.

Comment: If so, please consider to accept the answer @Brad63 How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

That is not the default setting. It must have been enabled in Preferences!
Go to Edit > Preferences, select the Keymap tab and uncheck 'Tab For Pie Menu' as shown below.

[image]

Comment: thank you for trying to help. The thing is, I have never checked Tab for Pie Menu so unchecking it isn't going to do anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have useful add-ons installed and some other handy settings it would be inconvenient to use a"reload factory settings" option. But this pie menu is indeed so irritating. I don't know how I'd switched to it. But the answer to get rid of it is in add-ons preferences. Find a "pie menu" add-on and untick all the pies except edit-delete pie menu.